# frontier node template fees

Tags: frontier, frontier-node-template

I created a new frontier node template with frontier.
During each interaction I pay a gas fee, my question is where this gas fee is deposited and can it be collected by the validator ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Transaction Payment Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/transaction-payment) is the pallet that provides the basic logic needed to pay the fees.

In the Config of the pallet you can configure how the fees are paid via `Config::OnChargeTransaction`.
Take a look about it configuration of this pallet in the frontier node template [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L276):

```
type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
```

You have to implement yourself how you want to deal with the fees.
A good idea is take a look of some implementations, a couple interesting I'd suggest you to look at are:

- Polkadot. It has a configuration for fees that splits 80% to treasury and 20% to author. Check [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L310) how is the configuration of the Transaction Payment Pallet:

```
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees<Runtime>>;
```

And the implementation of [DealWithFees](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/impls.rs#L39) that defines how to deal with the fees.

- [Rococo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/runtime/rococo) (Polkadot testnet), sends the fees to the author of the block. Check [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/src/lib.rs#L302) how is its configuration of the Transaction Payment Pallet.

```
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ToAuthor<Runtime>>;
```

And the implementation of [ToAuthor](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/impls.rs#L25) that sends the fees to the author of the block.

Answer (score 1):

When using frontier, you are mostly dealing with configurations of the various pallets, in this case, pallet-evm and maybe pallet-base-fee.

In addition to Alex's answer, the following may help provide you clarity:

```rust
pub struct EVMTransactionChargeHandler<OU>(PhantomData<OU>);
impl<OU> pallet_evm::OnChargeEVMTransaction for EVMTransactionChargeHandler<OU> {
  ...
}
```

This would be the **currency adapter** mentioned previously, as stated in the document for the trait: https://paritytech.github.io/frontier/rustdocs/pallet_evm/trait.OnChargeEVMTransaction.html

In the trait implementation you can put custom logic, for instance, what to do `on_unbalanced`. You can use https://paritytech.github.io/frontier/rustdocs/pallet_evm/struct.EVMCurrencyAdapter.html as a reference.

Note the generic arg `<OU>` which stands for the `Imbalance` handler. This is something that knows what to do with the `NegativeImbalance` that's generated on fee withdrawal. By providing an implementation for `OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance<_>>` you can determine what will ultimately be done with the fees collected. (i.e. whether it will go to a validator, be burned, or something else entirely)